# Generating log-normal random variables with specified mean of the variable and variance of the logarithm of the variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

In order to create a Monte-Carlo Simulation for Mertons Jump Diffusion Model I need to simulate a random variable $Y$, which is log-normally distributed. The mean of $Y$ is supposed to be $m$ and the variance of the logarithm of $Y$ should be $v^2$.
The problem I have is that I can only specify either both the mean and variance of the logarithm of $Y$ **or** both the mean and variance of $Y$ directly, via the following formulae (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Generation_and_parameters)):

$$
\mu=\ln \left(\frac{m^2}{\sqrt{m^2+v^2}}\right) \text { and } \sigma^2=\ln \left(1+\frac{v^2}{m^2}\right).
$$
$Y \sim \mathcal{LN}( \ln \left(\frac{k^2}{\sqrt{k^2+v^2}}\right),v^2)$ (as a combination of the two) unfortunately does not generate the desired distribution. I need a way to specify $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of the log-normal distribution that satisfies the above criterium.

**Edit:** I accidentally wrote that the variance of the logarithm of Y needs to be equal to $v$ instead of $v^2$. Thanks to heropup for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Y \sim \mathcal{LN}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then $\log(Y) \sim \mathcal{N} (\mu, \sigma^2)$. Hence the variance of the logarithm of $Y$ is equal to the variance of the normal distribution.

Since the variance of the logarithm of Y should be equal to $v^2$ and the log-normal distribution is defined by the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ of the underlying normal distribution, we can simply say that $\sigma^2=v^2$:

For the mean of $Y$ it's a bit more complicated:
If $\mu=0$, the log-normal distribution has a mean of $1$. Through transformation of $Y$ we can adjust the mean to be equal to $m$ without altering the variance of the logarithm of Y (with $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$):

$$
\log (m \cdot Y(\mu,\sigma^2)) = \log(m) + \log(Y(\mu,\sigma)^2) = \log(m) + X(\mu, \sigma^2) = X(\mu + \log (m),\sigma^2).
$$
As we can see, the adjustment of $Y$ does not change the variance of the logarithm of $Y$. Furthermore, we get the desired mean of $Y$ (with $\mu=0$ in mind):

$$
E[m \cdot Y(\mu,\sigma^2)] = m \cdot E[Y(\mu,\sigma^2)]  = m \cdot 1 =m,
$$

since the mean of $Y(0,\sigma^2) = 1$, as stated above.

Therefore, $m \cdot Y$ with $Y \sim \mathcal{LN}(0,v^2)$ yields the desired distribution.

Answer (score 0):

To generate realizations of a lognormal random variable $Y$ with desired mean $\operatorname{E}[Y] = m$ and variance $\operatorname{Var}[Y] = v$, we first generate a standard normal variate $Z$; then we multiply this by some scale parameter $\sigma$ and add some location parameter $\mu$ to get a normal random variate with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$; i.e., $$X = \sigma Z + \mu.$$  Then exponentiate $X$ to get $Y = e^X$, which will be lognormal with mean $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = \exp \left( \mu + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right) = m \tag{1}$$ and variance $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = (e^{\sigma^2} - 1) e^{2\mu + \sigma^2} = v. \tag{2}$$  All that remains now is to equate the above quantities with the desired mean and variance, and solve for the requisite location and scale parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in terms of $m$ and $v$.  In particular,
$$v = (e^{\sigma^2} - 1) m^2,$$ hence $$\sigma = \sqrt{\log \left(1 + \frac{v}{m^2}\right)}. \tag{3}$$  Then we have $$\mu = \log m - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} = \log m - \frac{1}{2} \log \left(1 + \frac{v}{m^2}\right) = \log \frac{m}{\sqrt{1 + v/m^2}} = \log \frac{m^2}{\sqrt{m^2 + v}}. \tag{4}$$

Your formula has confused the desired variance $v$ with the desired standard deviation.

In practice, suppose we want $Y$ to have mean $m = 7$ and variance $v = 15$.  Then the required location and scale parameters for the logarithm of $Y$ are $$\mu = \log \frac{7^2}{\sqrt{7^2 + 15}} = \log \frac{49}{8} \approx 1.81238, \\ \sigma = \sqrt{\log\left(1 + \frac{15}{7^2}\right)} \approx 0.516781.$$

However, to test that these formulas actually work by performing simulations and calculating the sample mean and variance, you will need to use a very large number of simulations because the convergence is extremely slow.  In $1000$ simulations, I got $m \approx 6.91724$ and $v \approx 14.3179$.  In $10^5$ simulations, I got $m \approx 7.00492$ and $v \approx 15.057$.  In $10^8$ simulations, I got $m \approx 7.00006$ and $v \approx 15.0007$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding mean and variance. However, I need the variance of the logarithm of Y to be equal to v^2 and the Y itself having the variance v^2.

Comment: @Cyanymous $v$ versus $v^2$ is a minor typo in this answer which explains fully where those Wikipedia formulas are coming from. Secondly: regardless what you start with: from any two of $\mu,\sigma,m,v$ you can derive the other two.

Comment: Maybe my new post can clarify this a bit more. With the formula, I can define $Y$ to have a ceratin mean and variance. I do not know the variance of $Y$, I only know the variance of the **logarithm** of $Y$. Only setting the mean through the formula changes the variance an vice versa.